# Natural Order Recalculation for a Ruby Spreadsheet Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, spreadsheet

I am working on a number of Rails-based projects which require spreadsheet-like functionality, so I would like to know if anyone ever tried to implement the Natural Order Recalculation algorithm in Ruby. If not, could you point out where can I find any guidelines so I can implement if myself. Oh, if anyone is interested, we will also open-source this part of our system :D

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "natural ordering" in spreadsheets is a special case of a more general idea called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), in which a set of objects with dependencies are sorted in a way such that each object is processed only after the objects on which it depends.  On this topic, I managed to find a few Ruby pages that describe topological sorting; [this one](http://blog.andrewcantino.com/blog/2010/01/29/using-tsort-in-ruby-for-topological-sorting-of-activerec/) might be a good starting point.  Although this isn't exactly what you need, the fact that there appears to be some kind of library support may make your job substantially easier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link, it certainly helped!